# Combining two simple scripts into single script in Python Parser of Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have two separate scripts used in Field Calculator for an "ID" attribute field.  Script 1 is to create sequential numbers for the field.  Script 2 is to add leading zeros to the sequential numbers.

Both scripts work independently, but is there a way to combine both scripts to run together as a single script?

**Script 1** (Pre-Logic Script Code)

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():

    global rec

    pStart = 4164 #adjust start value, if req'd

    pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd

      if (rec == 0): 

        rec = pStart 

     else: 
        rec = rec + pInterval

     return rec
```

**Script 1** (In smaller window)

```
autoIncrement()
```

**Script 2**

```
!ID!.zfill(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace 4164 with 04164, or 4165 with 04165, then just change:

```
 return rec
```

with:

```
return "0" + str(rec)
```

or if you need to have 7 places then:

```
return str(rec).zfill(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to populate the field with sequential numbers and then add leading zeros to all the populated numbers.  eg. 04164, 04165, and so on.  A co-worker and I found a solution by changing the script to:

```
rec=0
res = 0 
ren = 0

def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec
 global res
 global ren
 pStart = 4164  
 pInterval = 1 

  if (rec == 0):  
   rec = pStart
   res = str(rec)
   ren = res.zfill(7)
  else:  
   rec += pInterval
   res = str(rec)
  ren = res.zfill(7)  

 return ren
```

Comment: To say thanks please use your upvotes and/or the green accept checkmark.